# I am looking for a specific word that starts with the letter 'a' which concerns evidence presented in court

Tags: single-word-requests

The meaning of this word specifically either refers to evidence that has already been admitted or new evidence (I can't remember the context) and was utilized in this manner

> The a_______ evidence

I have tried searching up legal terms but none of them fit the bill. I am *not* looking for a compound word/phrase. This word had close to no synonyms in the Oxford dictionary.

Comment: Sounds like *"adduced"* is what you are looking for, but it could also be *"affidavit evidence"* (meaning the evidence from an affidavit, a voluntary written sworn statement).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The **adduced** evidence ...

> **adduce**
> *transitive verb*
> to offer as example, reason, or proof in discussion or analysis
> "adduce evidence in support of a theory"
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adduce)

Comment: This is the word I am looking for! Thank you.

Comment: "to bring forward in argument or as evidence; cite as pertinent or conclusive: to adduce reasons in support of a constitutional amendment." Dictionary.com

Answer (score 1):

*After-discovered evidence* is

> newly discovered evidence ... which existed at the time of the original trial but was only discovered after the conclusion of the trial.

Such evidence

> may be used as the basis for a motion for a new trial.

[LII](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/after-discovered_evidence)